# Swift - Checking if Array exists in Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm at a bit of a loss with regard to type checking values in a Swift Dictionary. I am expecting a dictionary of String -> AnyObject and want to ensure that the element at subscript "file" is an array before proceeding. Here's the code:

```
extension Array {
    static func ensureValueIsArray(arrayValue: AnyObject?) -> Array<AnyObject> {
        if let array = arrayValue as? Array<AnyObject>  {
            return array
        } else {
            return [AnyObject]()
        }
    }
}

func generateModel(responseDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> ResponseModel        
{
    var files = Array.ensureValueIsArray(responseDictionary["file"]) <--------- 
}
```

I am getting the following compiler error on the line indicated by the arrow: Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.

Any clues on how to get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite your extension method using generics:

```
extension Array {
    static func ensureValueIsArray(arrayValue: T?) -> Array<T> {
        if let array = arrayValue as? Array<T>  {
            return array
        } else {
            return [T]()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in playground:

```
generateModel(["file": [1, 2, 3]]) // Prints "[1, 2, 3]"
generateModel(["file": 1]) // Prints "0 elements"
generateModel(["something": 1]) // Prints "0 elements"
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio, that resolved the compiler error and now works as expected.